# NoMethodError when using hook methods in ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I'm going over the Ruby Bits course on Code School, and on level 5 they cover Modules.

On the hook methods part there's a certain challenge to add a self.included method hook for the LibraryUtils module which will extend the ClassMethods on the passed in class. The code follows:

```
module LibraryUtils

  def add_game(game)
  end

  def remove_game(game)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def search_by_game_name(name)
    end
  end
end

class AtariLibrary
  include LibraryUtils
  extend LibraryUtils::ClassMethods
end
```

Very simple and easy. First just include the said method in our module, like so:

```
def self.included(base)
  base.extend(ClassMethods)
end
```

And then just take out the extend so we wont have duplicity.

The problem is, when I try this outside of the codeschool environment (browser) with Ruby 2.0 I get a No Method Error:

```
atari_library.rb:27:in `<main>': undefined method `search_by_game_name' for #<AtariLibrary:0x2b07ef8> (NoMethodError)
```

Keep in mind here that I am using the same code.

Well, if anyone have any thoughts on this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling the method?

Comment: You got it in your answer! I was doing the bottom (wrong) example that you showed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of here that you're doing wrong is calling search_by_game_name on an instance of the AtariLibrary rather than the class, e.g:

```
AtariLibrary.search_by_game_name('name') # => works

al = AtariLibrary.new
al.search_by_game_name('name') # undefined method `search_by_game_name' for #<AtariLibrary:0x007fe3e204ebb0> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Class methods are methods that are called on a class so in this case AtariLibrary is a the class. You create an instance of it using the #new method which allows you to call instance methods ;-) If you're unsure of the difference between classes and instances maybe checkout: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: Or are you unsure of why ClassMethods become class methods? Maybe the difference between including a Module vs extending it?

Comment: Yeah, I was unaware of the difference between class and instance methods! Great link you posted, helped a lot!! Thank you again.